# What is the best way of writing this sentence?

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis

I want to say

> We know that Einstein gravity as it is, is not renormalizable in D=4.

in the beginning of a new section of my text. However, I am unsure about the repeated "is" verbs. Since I will use this as my opening sentence, I want to learn some other nice ways of writing it. Can anyone make suggestions?

Comment: as it is = [as such](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such#such__11)? There is also *[per se](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/per-se?q=per+se)*. I hope that it fits your context :-)

Comment: You want to say *Einstein**ian** gravity*, or *Einstein's gravity [model]*, but not *Einstein gravity*.

Comment: Actually "Einstein gravity" is good for the terminology I use, it is the common use in my study instead of the other two you suggested. @Lucky this is the first time I hear "per se" and I will look for the usage of it. However "as such", somehow, seems worse than "as it is" to me.

Comment: Who is your audience?  The sentence is riddled with jargon.  "Einstein gravity";  "renormalizable";  "in D=4".

Comment: It's a thesis on Physics and I am using the same notation/abbreviations of the articles I am studying. Anyway, the answer below is satisfactory and acceptable for me. Thanks for all the comments and for the care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To eliminate the repeated *is*, which is acceptable even if it is awkward, you can place the parenthetical phrase, *as it is*, before the noun phrase it modifies:

> We know that, ***as it is***, Einstein's gravity model is not normalizable
>   at D=4.